# Locate erroneous datapoints in dataframe python

Tags: python, csv, pandas, dataframe

I am working with large datasets (> 100.000, >100). The raw format is a CSV. I read the files as a `DataFrame` using the `pandas` library.

All data has to be of numerical type (integers of floats), however often it occurs that there is an missing data point, or an erroneous string in the original CSV file. It takes a lot of time to scan through the entire CSV, it the point(s) can be found at all. Therefore I'am trying to generate a function or class with which I can locate the errors. And provide their column and row name and/or number, to quickly trace them.

To experiment and construct the right algoritm I use a small dummy Dataframe, containing some sample erroneous datapoints. The desired outcome of locating the points would be for example: ['B', 2],  ['D', 4], using columns and index for location.

```
# Import dependency
import pandas as pd

# Create dummy DataFrame for testing
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
                   'B': [1, 1, '#', 1, 1],    # Undesired datapoint '#' to be located
                   'C': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
                   'D': [1, 1, 1, 1, '0']})   # Undesired datapoint '0' to be located
```

`

With the dummy dataframe I create a mask dataframe containing boolean statements of the original dataframe. In the mask all numerical values (`int` and `float`) are given a `True` and all non-numerical data as `False`.

```
df_mask = df.applymap(lambda x: isinstance(x, (int, float)))
```

Now at the part of locating the non-numerical data I get stuck. My best try is as follows, however it does not provide me the location of the `False` points.

```
df_cols = col for col if df_mask.loc[False].any()
```

What would be a way to grab the `False` locations of the masked dataframe (`df_mask`)?

Or is there even a quicker way to perform the tracking of erroneous data points in a `DataFrame`?

Answer (score 2):

I think you can create `Series` first by [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html), then create `mask` with `apply` and last filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing).

For values of index is necessary add [`remove_unused_levels`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.remove_unused_levels.html):

```
df = df.unstack()
df_mask = df.apply(lambda x: isinstance(x, (int, float)))

print (df[~df_mask])
B  2    #
D  4    0
dtype: object

print (df.index[~df_mask].remove_unused_levels().tolist())
[('B', 2), ('D', 4)]
```

EDIT:

If want extract non numeric values then use [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html) with `errors='coerce'` for convert values to `NaN`s and then check them:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
                   'B': [1, 1, '#', 1, 1],
                   'C': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
                   'D': [1, 1, 1, 1, '0']}).astype(str)

print (df.applymap(type))
               A              B              C              D
0  <class 'str'>  <class 'str'>  <class 'str'>  <class 'str'>
1  <class 'str'>  <class 'str'>  <class 'str'>  <class 'str'>
2  <class 'str'>  <class 'str'>  <class 'str'>  <class 'str'>
3  <class 'str'>  <class 'str'>  <class 'str'>  <class 'str'>
4  <class 'str'>  <class 'str'>  <class 'str'>  <class 'str'>

df = df.unstack()
df_mask = pd.to_numeric(df, errors='coerce').isnull()
print (df[df_mask])
B  2    #
dtype: object

print (df.index[df_mask].remove_unused_levels().tolist())
[('B', 2)]
```

Comment: Thank you very much jezrael, that really helped! (Sorry for the late reply.) However it only works when I set up a dummy dataframe as in the question. When I import the same data form a CSV as a dataframe using '    pd.read_csv    ' and then    unstack()    and apply the mask it returns    False    for all the values in the entire column where a row has a non-numerical value. Do you know what causes the difference?